# How do i write a search query that performs multiple tasks in Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, elk

I have read the Elasticsearch documentation. I also took a course. My questions is was how do I write one query to handle all my tasks? I learn by example. The documentation doesn't have many examples. I wrote what I think may be how I accomplish this task but I'm not sure i'm doing this correctly.

The ... is where i would put a match query of some sort

```
{
    "query": { 
        "bool": {
            "should": [
                {
                    "bool": {
                        "must": {
                            ...
                        },
                        "should": {
                            ...
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "bool": {
                        "query_string": {
                            ...
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "bool": {
                        ...
                    }
                },
                {
                "bool": {
                    "must": {
                        ...
                    },
                    "should": {
                        ...
                    }
                }
                }
            ],
            "minimum_should_match": 1
        }
    }
}
```

Is this how i would do it?

Answer (score 0):

The bool query contain array of [must, filter, should, mustnot] so you don't have to put another bool on it. Inside each of them you can write another bool query of course.

As you add a minimum_should_match, you right, you have to put it just after the should part. Your query has to look like :

```
{
    "query": { 
        "bool": {
             "should": [
                { "query_string" : ... },
                { "terms" : ... },
                { "bool" : ... },
                { "bool" : {
                        "must": [
                            {"query_string": ... },
                            {"bool": ....}
                        ]
                    }
                }
             ],
             "minimum_should_match": 1
        }
    }
}
```

You have a good example here:
https://www.compose.com/articles/elasticsearch-query-time-strategies-and-techniques-for-relevance-part-i/

https://hdmetor.github.io/how-to-combine-queries-in-es/